# Laravel socialite Google login cannot create credentials for localhost server

Tags: laravel, google-oauth, google-signin, laravel-socialite

I'm developing a laravel project with `socialite`. It is now in my `localhost` sever. During development, I want to test login/register locally. Hence, my domain is `localhost`.
I've created a project in google console but can't create credentials for my `localhost` domain.
https://console.developers.google.com/apis/credentials

When I try to add `localhost` to Authorized domains Google says `Invalid domain: must be a top private domain.` Here is a screenshot:

[image: Laravel Socialile credentials for localhost]

Is is possible to create credentials for `localhost`?

Comment: yes and no. `http://localhost` should work as a authorized domain. You have to add it first as such. Homelink can be `http://localhost/home`. Better is to mimic a full domain name. For example mytestserver.app or mydomain.dev. If you use xampp or similar, that's easy to do. Don't forget to add it to your `hosts` file. Google triggers on the request headers. This is true for any Google api service.

Comment: Ok. I can mimic domain name. Then, Google would not verify my terms and conditions links.